# How and where is returnUrl set, can it be overridden?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I've been looking into .NET CORE MVC and I keep seeing `returnUrl` referenced as a parameter in controller `GET` methods.  I'd like to understand how and where this value is set because right now it appears to be a product of fairy dust.

Any help in understanding this portion of the framework would be appreciated.

...and are there any other system type parameters that can be referenced as a parameter, if so is there a list somewhere and can you override how this logic behaves?

Comment: Is this your login page? With MVC if you hit an action that required authorization and your request is not authorized (or have the correct role) the browser is redirected to the specified login page (web.config) with the returnUrl as a parameter so that you can redirect the user to the original page once logged in.

Comment: @TomJohn, correct this is with the Login page, I should have probably clarified that but I wasn't sure if it affected any other views.  I'm in the process of learning cookie auth and then I'll transition over to the Identity framework.  As this is .NET CORE I don't have a web.config file but I do have a Startup file so I'm assuming it's just checking for the LoginPath there.

Comment: @TomJohn, I just found the variable that sets the name of this parameter, options.ReturnUrlParameter = "someothername";.  Thanks for leading me down this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MVC if you hit an action that required authorization and your request is not authorized (or have the correct role) the browser is redirected to the specified login page (web.config) with the returnUrl as a parameter so that you can redirect the user to the original page once logged in.